# Are svn usernames in authors file for git svn --authors-file case sensitive?

Tags: git-svn

I want to use `git svn` with [--authors-file=authors-file.txt](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt---authors-fileltfilenamegt), with `authors-file.txt`:

```
joe1 = Joe User <user@example.com>
Joe1 = Joe User <user@example.com>
JOE1 = Joe User <user@example.com>
```

Is the svn username case sensitive regarding `git svn --authors-file`? Will it still work if I omit the different variants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually going through this process at the moment, and can confirm that Git is case sensitive here even if the operatng system isn't. If you ommit those entries from you authors file then Git will fail with an `author not defined` error when attempting to clone from SVN.